# How can I assert that a function is called with certain arguments? (the function is called more than once in the parametrization)

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

```
# function to test
def example_function(intdate): 
    for date in all_dates: 
        parser(group, name, date) 
        ...



# test function
@pytest.mark.parametrize("intdate, expected_all_dates",
                         (20190624, 20190625, 20190626, 20190627, 20190628, 20190629),
                         (['20190623', '20190624'], ['20190625'], ['20190626'],
                          ['20190627'], ['20190628'], ['20190629']))
@mock.patch("<path_to_parser>")
def test_all_dates(mock_parser, intdate, expected_all_dates): 

    example_function(intdate)

    assert mock_parser.<something>.call_args_list??
```

I tried to use `assert_call_with`, but notice in the parametrization that in the first case, it calls on `parser()` twice. And I'm not sure how to assert things in this example.
I thought about using `side_effect` but I am not sure how to incorporate it here. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Sorry but I can only imagine your real problem. Add more **complete** code and improve the question please.